# Ruby / Sinatra JSON.parse is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, sinatra

the String that I'm trying to parse is:

```
{\"user_name\":\"test@test.com\",\"pass\":\"bla\"}


[3] pry(#<Flockers::WebApp>)> JSON.parse(request.body.read)
JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!
from c:/WebTools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json_pure-1.8.1/lib/json/commo
n.rb:155:in `initialize'
```

When I execute JSON.parse in javascript, this works, but this is not parsing properly in ruby console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error can be caused by passing JSON.parse an empty string. Try running `request.body.rewind` before `request.body.read`.